# getopts: How to accept arguments that aren't tied to an option in my script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, terminal

I'm writing a Bash script that has the following usage:

```
ci-badge -t|-a [-b branch] [-m] [-d description] [-l [link] ] repo
```

Examples:

```
$ ci-badge -t foo/bar
$ ci-badge -ab dev foo/bar -m
$ ci-badge quux/bar -md 'Hello, world.'
```

More samples can be found [here](https://github.com/jamesqo/ci-badge#usage) on GitHub. Anyway, I'm wondering exactly how to implement argument parsing for this script using `getopts`. After a few hours looking at [this](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial) basic `getopts` guide and scouring SO, this is what my code looks so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

generate_url=false # set to true if -l is passed with no arg
markdown=false # true -> surround the URL with markdown

# Parse options
while getopts ':tab:md:l:' opt
do
    case "$opt" in
        a) service=appveyor ;;
        b) branch=$OPTARG ;;
        d) description=$OPTARG ;;
        l) url=$OPTARG ;;
        m) markdown=true ;;
        t) service=travis ;;
        # Colon: runs if no args are passed to
        # an option that normally requires parameters.
        :) test "$OPTARG" = l && generate_url=true ;;
        # ?: Runs if an invalid option is passed.
        '?') die ;;
    esac
done
```

As you can see, most of the functionality is there, but I'm wondering how to accept `repo` as an argument to the script. Since `getopts` stops parsing after it encounters the first non-option argument, I'm wondering, how would I implement this (preferably with minimal complexity)? The [guide](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial) I linked earlier doesn't seem to mention dealing with arguments that aren't associated with an option, so I'm a bit lost.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: @ConspicuousCompiler The question/answer you linked to does not handle any arguments that aren't tied to an option, unfortunately.

Comment: doesn't `case "$opt" in ..... ;; * ) unpaired_arg=$1 ; other_stuff with "$unpaired_arg" ; .. more ... ;; esac` get you most of the way there? Good luck.

Comment: @JamesKo Note that I said "scroll down to the getopt solution".  It very specifically handles options beyond what getopt processes.

Answer (score 0):

Use $OPTIND value. After getopts cycle:

```
shift $((OPTIND-1))
echo $@
echo $1 $2 ...
```